# Program that asks user to input quiz scores and gives back a letter grade

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, switch-statement

I need help writing a program that asks for the user to input a grade that is out of 10 and then it will give back the corresponding letter grade "A,B,C,D,F" I need to use a for loop with a switch statement. How can I start this?

Comment: Start as you would with any program - your main function!  Then start to add each piece, and go from there.

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far. It will help us to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the use of the for loop would be. After storing the input into an integer variable, you could use a switch statement for each available case. For this, you'd have cases 0-10. Example:

```
switch (int name here){
    case 1: System.out.println("F");
    break;
    case 2: System.out.println("F");
    break;
//Continue for each available number and the grade corresponding to it.
```

Comment: You could also use an if/else if statement which will save you some coding for cases 0-5 ("F"). 

if (intName < 6){ System.out.println("F");}

Answer (score 0):

you can fill switch with more case / system.out.print to finish this
it will stop it you enter quit

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            String f = scan.nextLine(); //Scans user input for name
            if (f.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")){
                return;
            }
            try {
                int num = Integer.parseInt(f);
                if (num <= 10){
                    switch(num){
                        case 1:
                            System.out.println("F");
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```